# pip install pydot raises a SyntaxError

Tags: python, syntax-error, pip

I'm running pip from the command line, trying to install pydot because Django's django-extensions needs it to generate UML class diagrams

When I run the command `pip install pydot`, it gives me this error:

```
Collecting pydot
  Using cached pydot-1.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uscu27_d\pydot\setup.py
", line 5
        except ImportError, excp:
                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The same error happens with `easy_install pydot`.

Looks like the correct syntax would be `except ImportError as excp`, but I don't know what to do about this. The version of Python I'm using is 3.4.3. Do I have to downgrade my version of Python to get this to work, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is due to the old `exception` syntax of python2.

Since `pydot` seems to be a very old library and no longer maintained, I'd suggest forking it and correct this error yourself.

Comment: I have python 2.7.11 but I get the same error as well