# Pydot syntax error on Windows

Tags: python, syntax-error, pip

I am trying to install a virtual environment on Windows and I am having the same problem as here: [pip install pydot raises a SyntaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249371/pip-install-pydot-raises-a-syntaxerror)

I tried to comment, but I don't have 50 reputation in order to comment.  I can fix the error, but the problem that I am having is where is the setup.py file that I am suppose to edit so that pip can see it? How am I suppose to make pip see the change I did in the setup file so that I don't get an error like this again?

I have downloaded the version that pip is trying to install (1.0.2) and fixed the problem myself, then copied it to the `lib\site-packages\` directory, but it does not work.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Download it using Git, update `setup.py` in the downloaded folder, then compile(+install) yourself :

```
$ git clone https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot
$ cd pydot
$ nano ./setup.py
$ python ./setup.py install
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.